# Do dividends paid on short positions count when reporting taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, dividends

If I'm long **Company A** that paid me $100 in dividends and I'm short **Company B** that I paid $100 in dividends...

do I report $0.00 to the IRS? Do I sum dividends in and out?

Comment: Read this: https://www.fool.com/taxes/2002/12/06/dividends-paid-on-short-sales.aspx

Comment: Also this: https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550#en_US_2018_publink100010598

Comment: Please don't post answers in the comments.